# How to check which page is the aspx homepage in SP Online with React Spfx

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

If I am on a site collection and the homepage isn't "Home.aspx", how can I check which one is it using react SPFX framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use pnp library to get the welcome page.

```
pnp.sp.web.get().then(web=>{
      console.log(web.WelcomPage);
    })
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-sp-pnp-js-with-spfx-web-parts

Answer (score 0):

This combination worked for me :

```
pnp.setup({
  spfxContext: this.props.context
});
let welcomePage = await pnp.sp.web.get().then(web=>{
  return web.WelcomePage;
})
```